# Arraylist IndexOutOfBoundsException? Need some help on this

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

I keep getting an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` when I run my code. I am using an `ArrayList` so I'm not sure why this is happening.
My `ArrayList` is

```
ArrayList<Card> cards = new ArrayList<Card>();
```

This is where the error occurs

```
public static void printCard(){
    System.out.printf("%-20s %-20s\n", player1.name, player2.name);
    for(int i = 0; i < 24; i++){
        System.out.printf("%-20s %-20s\n", player1.getCard(i), player2.getCard(i));
    } System.out.println();
}
```

Player class

```
public class Player {

    public Deck mainDeck;
    public Deck sideDeck;
    public String name;
    public int duelsWon;
    public int totalCompares;

    public Player(String name){
        this.name=name;
        mainDeck = new Deck();
        sideDeck = new Deck();
        duelsWon = 0;
        totalCompares = 0;
    }

    public void addCard(Card newCard){
        sideDeck.addCard(newCard);
    }

    public Card drawCard() throws OutOfCardsException{
        if(mainDeck.numCards() == 0) {
            addSideDeck();
        }
        if(mainDeck.numCards() == 0){
            throw new OutOfCardsException();
        }
        Card c = mainDeck.drawCard();
        return c;
    }
    public Card getCard(int i){
        return mainDeck.cards.get(i);
    }
    /*public Card getCard(int i){
        if(i < mainDeck.cards.size()) {
            return mainDeck.cards.get(i);
        }else{

        }
        return null;
    }*/

    public void addSideDeck(){
        sideDeck.shuffle();
        System.out.println("sideDeck: " + sideDeck.numCards());
        for(int i = 0; i < sideDeck.numCards(); i++){
            Card c = sideDeck.drawCard();
            mainDeck.addCard(c);
        }
    }

}
```

Deck class

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

public class Deck {


    ArrayList<Card> cards = new ArrayList<Card>();

    public Deck() {

    }
    public void addCard(Card c){
        cards.add(c);
    }
    public Card drawCard(){
        Card c = cards.remove(cards.size() - 1);
        return c;
    }
    public Card getCard(){
        return cards.get(cards.size() - 1);
    }
    public int numCards(){
        return cards.size();
    }
    public void shuffle()
    {
        int index;
        Card temp;
        Random random = new Random();
        for (int i = cards.size() - 1; i > 0; i--)
        {
            index = random.nextInt(i + 1);
            temp = cards.get(index);
            cards.set(index, cards.get(i));
            cards.set(i, temp);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this code is not enough to tell.

Comment: Please add the complete stacktrace

Comment: Sorry about that. I just added my player and deck classes.

Comment: The exception tells you what's wrong - you are accessing index 6 in an `ArrayList` that only has 6 elements (i.e. has indexes 0,1,2,3,4,5)

Comment: Unfortunately I still don't think you've provided enough information. You would get the ArrayOutOfBoundsException when i is greater than or equal to cards.size() in the cards ArrayList of the Deck class, but you haven't shown how you are adding cards to the deck class. If mainDeck for each player doesn't have at least 24 cards then you will always see this error.

Comment: You should always avoid a fixed value in the for loop, like  "for(int i = 0;i<24;i++)". Instead use something like  "for(int i = 0; i < cards.size(); i++) {". Or use a for-each loop "for(Card card : cards) {"

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that you don't have 24 cards in your deck for one of your players. Nothing else will cause this with this code.

Answer (score 0):

What is 24 ?

i think you need to check card size.

```
public static void printCard(){
    System.out.printf("%-20s %-20s\n", player1.name, player2.name);
    for(int i = 0; i < cards.size(); i++){
        System.out.printf("%-20s %-20s\n", player1.getCard(i), player2.getCard(i));
    } System.out.println();
}
```

I hope it help.

Answer (score 0):

`IndexOutOfBoundsException` happens when you are trying to access an item which index is beyond the items stored in the ArrayList. Ex, if an ArrayList contains 5 items (index from 0 to 4) then if you try to access the ArrayList with index 5 then IndexOutOfBoundsException would be thrown.

Best approach to iterate though ArrayList/List are like:

```
for (Card c: cards) {
}
```

Or looping to the size

```
for (int i=0; i<cards.size(); i++) {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is some issue with Random number you are getting

```
index = random.nextInt(i + 1);
temp = cards.get(index);
```

Just log the index and check if it is between 0 to cards.size();